# Examples from the Nikkor Micro 105mm f/2.8 on a full frame camera

Tags: lens, nikon, macro, picture-samples

This is more of a request than a question. I'm considering getting the aforementioned lens but I'm a bit afraid that it may not allow me to produce as much magnification as I would hope for. That's why I would like to ask users of this lens to post pictures or links to pictures taken with this lens and a full frame camera. Show me how "big" it can go.

Answer (score 4):

Here are many samples:
[Pbase.com](http://www.pbase.com/cameras/nikon/105_28g_ed_if_afs_vr_micro)

Out of the 16k photos there, I'm sure some are with a d700.  A bit hard to narrow down the search there, but still, a good way to get some impressions.

For what it's worth, [Bjørn Rørslett](http://www.naturfotograf.com/index2.html) did not particularly like this lens in comparison with the 200mm or the 60mm, while [Thom Hogan](http://www.bythom.com/qadmacro.htm) doesn't understand the point of a 60mm, since the 1:1 focal distance is so close to the front element that most bugs will be spooked by it.  I find both of those reviewers to give very thorough, detailed critiques of lenses, and coupled with the samples on pbase, I have a much better idea of what to expect.

Answer (score 1):

It's a 1:1 lens, so that means that the size of the subject will be the same size on the sensor. Meaning, for example, a 10mm x 10mm square will project exactly 10mm x 10mm on the sensor at the 1:1 focus point. To go beyond that, you need extension tubes or multipliers.

Anyways, reviews on the lens rate it very high. Like most macro lenses, it's razor sharp.